# Ubuntu doesn't seem to shut down unless I force kill it. suggestions?

Tags: shutdown

When I am logged in, I press shut down and it logs out. from the log in screen I try to shut down and nothing happens. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It sounds like you are experiencing [bug 838792](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792). If this matches the issue you are facing, could you please follow the link and mark yourself as affected on the bug report? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score 2):

From the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792) I linked to, it sounds like some people resolved this issue by various means:

- Reinstalling all `gnome-keyring` packages
- Running

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
  ```

  in a terminal, then removing the `autologin-user= YOUR USERNAME` line and running

  ```
  sudo shutdown -h now
  ```
- Killing `plexmediaserver`, if installed
- Doing a fresh reinstall of the whole OS

I have not tried any of these methods myself (I was previously affected but not anymore), so I cannot say from personal experience which of these would likely work for you. Be sure to backup any data before trying any of these suggestions.